# MobileConnect - Concatenation not supported - Forcing a break

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I'm running SMSs in an area where concatenation of the message is not supported.

The messages I have are being truncated mid-sentence.  Is there any way of forcing the truncation at a fixed point (i.e. between sentences) so that the message formats in a more customer friendly way?

Comment: So truncation happens at 160 characters is most markets, so you could possibly write your message with extra spaces to split a word/sentence as this spot

Comment: Hi @Thomas Hockey, can you provide a few examples of the text you are trying to send? Messages will truncate at ~150-160 characters (Assuming GSM encoding and not UTF-8/16) since the payload must also include the message header (From Number). Do you know the maximum total message length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to solve this using a Script activity and a triggered SMS.

The SSJS below can take any string and break it into the desired length:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
  function splitter(str, l){
    var strs = [];
    while(str.length > l){
        var pos = str.substring(0, l).lastIndexOf(' ');
        pos = pos <= 0 ? l : pos;
        strs.push(str.substring(0, pos));
        var i = str.indexOf(' ', pos)+1;
        if(i < pos || i > pos+l)
            i = pos;
        str = str.substring(i);
    }
    strs.push(str);
    return strs;
}
  var sampletext = "Toilet paper attack claws fluff everywhere meow miao french ciao litterbox murr i hate humans they are so annoying. Please stop looking at your phone and pet me really likes hummus purr as loud as possible, be the most annoying cat that you can, and, knock everything off the table who's the baby, or fat baby cat best buddy little guy.";
var outputString = splitter(sampletext, 140);
  Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(outputString));
</script>
```

**Output**: (3 string objects under 140 characters each)

> ["Toilet paper attack claws fluff everywhere meow miao french ciao litterbox murr i hate humans they are so annoying. Please stop looking at", 
>   "your phone and pet me really likes hummus purr as loud as possible, be the most annoying cat that you can, and, knock everything off the", 
>   "table who's the baby, or fat baby cat best buddy little guy."]

Original Code Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624713/js-splitting-a-long-string-into-strings-with-char-limit-while-avoiding-splittin

Now that the full SMS string has been broken into compliant lengths, you could use the [Post Message to Number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm) REST API to trigger each message-part off to the customer as individual messages.

You may want to add a small [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873323/javascript-sleep-wait-before-continuing/16873849) or [promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) container to ensure the messages are processed by the SMS service in a sequential order. Note that the end user may still receive them out of order due to environmental factors (bad reception).

Comment: Thank you for this detail.  The problem is compounded by needing to use dynamic values - meaning that possible lengths are variable, so it's difficult to know where to put a break!

I think the answer may be to remove dynamic copy - which actually removes any need to set a break in the SMS.

Thank you for your help though.